# flutter firebase authentication Error after publishing on google play say the code not true send again

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-play-services

I have a problem with firebase authentication by phone number process,
I have copied SHA-1 from App Signing, And I pasted it in firebase fingerprint,
The problem that I face now is that when I enter the phone number, a message is sent correctly, but when I enter the code, the authentication fails. notes, this problem does not exist when the application is running on a Debug mode, just when app on google play

Comment: Did you upload release SHA1 fingerprint to firebase

Comment: yes i copied  SHA-1 from app signing from google play console and i pasted in firebase

Comment: There are two SHA1 fingerprints debug and release , make sure you have entered both  in firbase console

Answer (score 0):

Update SHA-1 Key in Firebase project setting

[image]

Also check your google cloud project api key setting and also add SHA-1 Key credentials if you have Key restrictions.

[image]